# Can I disable or remove Ultimate Vault Hunter Mode?

Tags: borderlands-2

I am thoroughly tired of playing Ultimate Vault Hunter Mode (UVHM). I know this is supposed to be the most challenging mode of all. However, playing it feels like a chore and without anyone to play with I'm forced to adapt to the only survivable playstyle. This is not fun.

I would like to play TVHM, but my character keeps leveling (currently 53). Is it possible to somehow disable or uninstall just the UVHM upgrade pack DLC, reverting my level cap to 50? Also, would that reduce my character's level back to 50 and if not, can I do it in another way?

The game was purchased on Steam and I wish to keep it that way. I already disabled the DLC through Steam, but my character can still be played in UVHM and its level is unchanged.

Comment: I can't answer your question, but I'm planning on playing Borderlands 2 eventually, could you please elaborate more about how UVHM gets tiresome? here in the comments as that is not part of the question.

Comment: Just put UVHM into google - crying people all over forums. I was really into UVHM at first - more skills, stronger enemies, it all seemed to work out. A lot of people claim it's too hard - and it is really hard, but with right attitude it manageable. Problem is it completely changes the feel of the game. In normal you rack up level and skills to slaughter enemies. In TVHM you optimise items and skills to fight on more or less even grounds. In UVHM there is only one way to play - get a team, farm particular legendary items, use slag every other bullet. Unless you have a friend it's a chore.

Comment: You can easily disable the specific "Borderlands 2: Ultimate Vault Hunters Upgrade Pack"  DLCs from the DLC tab of the game's property page, but I don't know what effect this would have your already existing character. It's possible that you won't be able to play with it.

Comment: @eimyr Huh interesting I only have like 3 gamer friends and none of them like Borderlands, despite what I say to them. So I will be most likely playing the game alone, thanks for the info.

Comment: @Zerjack It's definitely worth playing alone, but it's better with a group. In fact, apart from the poor experience with UVHM I enjoyed the game twice. The 4 big dlcs are worth purchasing as well, just don't bother doing them during your main campaign. The best way IMO is to play the game once on normal, then speedrun main story on TVHM and hit lvl 50. Afterwards you can finish all the sidequests and do DLCs - I found that the most fun approach. Doing DLCs earlier disrupts your leveling and you end up being overleveled.

Comment: @eimyr - I found Borderlands 2 too grindy overall - In general the weapons felt "Ok" unless you went and grinded bosses for the specific weapons. Borderlands 1, the weapons felt "great" in general, with the boss' guns giving "alternate" styles of play, as opposed to strictly 'better' guns.

Comment: @Robotnik I actually feel the other way. Different manufacturers in BL1 made pretty similar weapons - OK, sometimes they had a minor gimmick, but overall there was a lot of strictly better loot - like anything made by Atlas. In BL2 while the legendaries truly do not give you a very different experience, differences between mundane weapons are exaggerated and fun. I mean, I didn't find much difference between Unkempt Harold and regular Torgue multishot pistol, but torgue and vladof pistols feel very different.

Answer (score 1):

At the BL2 menu, just select New Game to start over with a new character.

Or if you want to keep playing your original character in order to finish any missions you missed, do a Save-Quit to get back to the main menu, then press a button (Y on the Xbox 360) to bring up a list of characters you have played, even if it's just the current character. When you select the current character from the list, your next option is to play the starting level or True Vault Hunter.